# How do I `use` a namespace in Yii and HAML?

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, haml, yii2

I'm using [MTHAML](https://github.com/mervick/yii2-mthaml) and Yii. I have the following lines.

```
-use yii\helpers\Url
%a{:href => Url::toRoute(['shopping/ping', 'id' => (string)$item->productId, 'category' => (string)$item->primaryCategory->categoryId])} test
```

However it gives an error.

#### syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

```
<?php
 
function __MtHamlTemplate_65307eb071e28021db686cb46d491c8faae477235051858b05f212731637dd40($__variables)
{
    extract($__variables);
?><?php use yii\helpers\Url; ?>
```

Comment: You've got a dash in front of your use statement. Should that be there? It doesn't look right

Comment: @JoeMiller That's HAML! You'll love it! http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_

Comment: :-) never used it, but I must admit to being somewhat intrigued. I'll have to use the php version though, can't be arsed with setting up a ruby server.

Comment: Well of course! They have versions for PHP too! Try the non-Yii https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fixed this bug today.
Update your package by running:

```
composer update
```

or download latest release [0.1.3](https://github.com/mervick/yii2-mthaml/releases/tag/0.1.3) from GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Because of the namespace invalid when compile html cached.
Please try this from root nb

```
%a{:href => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['shopping/ping', 'id' => (string)$item->productId, 'category' => (string)$item->primaryCategory->categoryId])} test
```

Comment: `Unexpected '\', expected target language expression in /.../_list.haml on line 11, column 19`